# Все ли знаки на месте?

Tags: пунктуация

"На площадке выступил главный любимец публики, восходящая звезда стантрайдинга( )Никита Подольский".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"любимца бублики". Мне нравится! Я думаю, можно поставить тире, т.к. Никита Подольский - это приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь по смыслу вторая запятая не нужна. "Восходящая звезда" - не уточнение "любимца публики", а скорее однородное с ним.

Answer (score 1):

**Знаки в Вашем примере все на месте**. Я **не согласна** с Инной. ***Никита Подольский - это определяемое слово***, а вот "главный любимец публики, восходящая звезда стантрайдинга" - приложения. **Тире не нужно**, так как однородные  приложения стоят перед определяемым словом. Разве что интонационно очень захочется выделить имя "звезды".
Собственное имя, точнее имя и фамилия лица,  редко бывает приложением. "При сочетании нарицательного и собственного имени (фамилии) человека **приложением является имя нарицательное**: директор Ушаков, брат Иван" (http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_4_1)

Comment: Все правильно!